# Different CV for applying to university and applying to fellowship?

Tags: application, funding, cv

After reading through all (yes, all) questions in the [cv](/questions/tagged/cv) tag, I have a thought that CVs for applying to a position of a university are different to CVs for applying to a fellowship. When applying to a position of a university, the quality of the CV is define by your papers, research experiences, education, etc. While when applying to a fellowship, a good CV is the one can show your leadership, volunteering jobs, etc. Yes, there are some overlapped sections, but these two are not the same. Are CVs for applying to universities different to applying to fellowships?

Comment: Can you give some details on the kind of fellowship you're asking about?

Comment: A CV should be tailored for a particular fellowship just like a resume/CV for a job (any job) should be.

Comment: @silvado sorry for the late respond. I missed the notification. My fellowship is a fund from US gov, only give for STEM field. Every year it receives apps from my country and hold an interview to select.

Comment: @mkennedy and what about CV for universities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike a resume, the contents of your CV should typically be comprehensive and complete, including both research experience and service.  You might want to reshuffle the positions of sections within the CV for a target where you want to emphasize one aspect vs. another, but the content should be no different.